# How can I get variable set of attributes in my XML configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Each mode I am executing has slightly different behaviour from each other, so an atribute I define in the settings configuration xml file may be different for each one

for example take this xml

```
 <MyFunction Mode="Mode1" >
    <ModeSettings ModeRange="all" ModeId="12">
 </MyFunction >
```

represented by these classes

```
public class MyFunction
{
    [XmlAttribute("Mode")]
    public UserMode Mode { get; set; }

    public List<ModeSettings> ModeSettings { get; set; }
}
```

settings that apply to specific mode

```
public class ModeSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("ModeRange")]
    public string Range { get; set; }

}
```

Settings that apply only to a different mode

```
public class ModeSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("ModeRange")]
    public string Range { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("ModeId")]
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

So for instance the ModeId attribute may not apply to all modes.  How do I handle this in my XML and my configuration classes?

Comment: Make `id` nullable int and provide null for those modes which should not have `ModeId` attribute

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I cam across ShouldSerializeAction, would that work as well?